# delete request is not working on postman :

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

const usersList = [{id :1,name:"naser",age:26},{id :2,name:"mosa",age:46}];


app.post('/users',(req,res)=>{
    const newUser = req.body;
    usersList.push(newUser);
    res.status(200).json(usersList)
})

app.delete(`/users/:userId`,(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.userId    ;
    usersList.filter(user => {
        user.id !== id
        
    })
    res.status(200).json(usersList)
})

app.listen('3500',()=>
console.log("our server is running")
)
```

the delete request returns the same array without deleting when i hit "http://localhost:3500/users/2"

whats wrong ?

Comment: `.filter` returns a **new array**.

Comment: with ```.filter()``` u create a new array and dont modify the existing userList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` won't change the original array. You need to get the new array and return it.

```js
app.delete(`/users/:userId`,(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.userId    ;
    const newUsersList = usersList.filter(user => user.id !== id)
    res.status(200).json(newUsersList)
})
```

And if you want to change the real `usersList`, just assign the return value to it instead of assigning it to a new variable named `newUsersList`

```
usersList = usersList.filter(user => user.id !== id)
```

### EDIT

you can use below code to remove user from `usersList`

```
app.delete(`/users/:userId`,(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.userId;
    usersList = usersList.filter(user => user.id !== id)
    res.status(200).json(usersList)
})
```

### UPDATE

based on the comments. the type of `id` is string. for make filter to works as you expected you have 2 options:

#### First

you can check the equality with `!=`

```js
usersList = usersList.filter(user => user.id != id)
```

#### Second

you can place `+` in front of `req.params.userId` or use `Number` or `parseInt` functions.

```js
const id = +req.params.userId;

// or
const id = Number(req.params.userId);

// or 
const id = parseInt(req.params.userId);
```

Comment: This still won't update the original user list, so deleting a user won't work.

Comment: @CherryDT you're right. But my point was to demonstrate that filter won't change the original array. I added the Edit section to address your concern.

Comment: I tried the edit , and it returned an empty array !

Comment: I'm sorry, I just copied the filter function from your code. You need to remove curly braces in the filter.

Comment: now it returned to the same problem , it does not delete anything

Comment: cause you're comparing the id with triple equal sign. you receive the id from request in string format and you're comparing it with a number. it always will return true, and won't filter anything.